# Why I get this error: Query fired: did not receive all answers in time for graph.facebook.com:443 in xcode react-native app

Tags: ios, react-native, fbsdk

I have a basic react-native app for ios that loads an webview and I installed react-native-fbsdk-next module to get the auto events in facebook app but there is no activity in facebook event manager and I have this error in xcode when I run app on my device (iPhone SE ios 15.1):

> nw_resolver_start_query_timer_block_invoke [C3] Query fired: did not receive all answers in time for graph.facebook.com:443

I followed all the install instruction in the docs.

This is my package.json

```
...
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.63.4",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^8.0.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-iap": "^7.5.0",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.14.5",
    "react-native-web": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "11.6.2"
...
```

And the initialization code in my App.js file

```
...
export default function App() { 
...
const requestTrackingPermission = async () => {
    const res = await request(PERMISSIONS.IOS.APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY);
    return res === RESULTS.GRANTED || res === RESULTS.UNAVAILABLE;
  };

  (async function () {
    
    if (!attGranted) {
      const userAllowsTracking = await requestTrackingPermission();
      if (userAllowsTracking) {
        Settings.setAdvertiserTrackingEnabled(true).then(() => {
          setAttGranted(true);
        });
      }    
    }

    Settings.initializeSDK();
    
  }
  )();

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following on your iPhone:

1. `Settings`
2. `Privacy & Security`
3. `Tracking`
4. Toggle on `Allow Apps to Request to Track`
5. Launch `Facebook` app
6. Click `Allow`

After this, I was able to remove this warning.